# Javascript Fetch calling WCF - 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, wcf, fetch-api

Learning JavaScript, I have WCF services running on my local machine. IIS version is 10.

I'm trying to consume one of the methods by using JavaScript FETCH in the browser's console. The promise says 'fulfilled' but the method is not allowed. Googling it shows it CORS related, so I've added a header in my website header to allow (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`). I can't edit the WCF's operation contract as I'm just hosting them (test services).

Is there any way I can see the data? I can access the services and the method using WCF Test Client.

I also tried using some cross origin proxy, it works, but how do I see the data like the output of WCF Test Client?

```
async function test(){
 let s = await fetch('http://localhost/Main/Oriol.Host.BussServer/FinancialService.svc/GetAllTaxGroups',{
method: 'GET', 
cache: 'no-cache', 
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'   
}})).then(a => a.json());
console.log(s);
}
```

EDIT:

Here's the interface...

```
<service name="Oriol.Financial.Service.FinancialService" behaviorConfiguration="OriolServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="restWebHttpBinding" contract="Oriol.Financial.Domain.ServiceInterfaces.IFinancialService" />
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="OriolBasicHttpBinding" contract="Oriol.Financial.Domain.ServiceInterfaces.IFinancialService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PortSharingBinding" contract="Oriol.Financial.Domain.ServiceInterfaces.IFinancialService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

This is the FinancialService.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Oriol.Financial.Service.FinancialService" %>
```

Error:

> GET  http://localhost/Main/Oriol.Host.BussServer/FinancialService.svc/GetAllTaxGroups 405 (Method Not Allowed)
> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

This is the response:

> Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost/Main/Oriol.Host.BussServer/FinancialService.svc/GetAllTaxGroups", redirected: false, status: 405, ok: false, …}
> body: (...)
> bodyUsed: false
> headers: Headers {}
> ok: false
> redirected: false
> status: 405
> statusText: "Method Not Allowed"
> type: "cors"
> url: "http://localhost/Main/Oriol.Host.BussServer/FinancialService.svc/GetAllTaxGroups"
> **proto**: Response

**Resolution:**

Added in config file.

```
<customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" /> 
</customHeaders>
```

Also, closer inspection in Fiddler showed Security only allows POST. I didn't need any other header params except the Method.

All working now, thanks everyone.

Comment: you have to see if this endpoint requires a POST

Comment: You have to keep the promise chain alive.

Comment: I can add another .then(), and another maybe, but what should I put inside when I don't know what it returns? any ideas?

Comment: Look up examples on how to use fetch.

Comment: `but I don't see any data` ... that's because you're using `mode: 'no-cors'` - that mode doesn't "defeat" CORS, it allows you to make a CORS request when you don't need to see the response

Comment: with `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` your server will need to respond appropriately to an `OPTIONS` pre-flight request, and the actual response to the `POST` will need CORS headers too - also, why are you using method `POST` with no post data?

Comment: You need to check whether your server uses the same method as the client. You use the POST method on the client, then the server should also use the POST method. At the same time, it should be noted that the String value of the Method attribute in the service contract attribute should be all uppercase.

Comment: Can you post your service interface?

Comment: Hi Ding, i"ve updated the code above. cheers

Comment: 405 method not allowed means your usage of a `GET` method in your client does not match what your server allows (maybe `POST`?)

Comment: This may be an error in the request format. Can you use the browser to send the request? WCF provides help documents for REST services. You can check how to request services correctly by enabling help documents. For information about help document, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-service-help-page